# 405 HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed after azure ad

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis-7.5

We are doing azure ad authentication from a ASPX page.
We are able to  pass the authentication and  getting redirected to the redirectURI.
After this , I am getting 405 error

Ex : URL  :   https://test.com/abc   -> getting  authenticated with azure ad 
    Redirect URL :  https://test.com/abc  -> getting 405 error

405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.

Web.config changes

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: make sure you installed the .net feature properly in iis. sometimes the web.config file entry cause this issue. what is the entry in your applicationhost.conifg file? try to uninstall the web dev module. you could refer this link for more detail [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications) ,[link2](https://weblogs.asp.net/senthil/http-405-error-with-web-api)

Comment: The particular webapplication doesnot have web dev module. I am able to get the token after openid connect,  but the page is not getting loaded...

Comment: One doubt,  the  requested page URL is https://test.com/abc/ , and the redirect url from openid is https://test.com/abc  ...Will the trailing slash cause an issue?

Comment: in my opinion, it does not create any issue just make sure the request URL exists in your site. try to use the fiddler and check which verb is used.also enable the failed request tracing to check if module.http verb reject the request.